# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: mysqli object is already closed in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo registros a mi base de datos pero al momento de registrar me sale este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: mysqli object is already closed in ...

Espero puedan ayudarme

este es el código para insertar.

```
 <?php

include ("conexion.php");

$paterno = $_POST["paterno"];
$materno = $_POST["materno"];
$nombres = $_POST["nombres"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$curso = $_POST["curso"];

// INSERTAR DATOS A LA BASE 
$insertar = "INSERT INTO registro (paterno, materno, nombres, correo, telefono, direccion, curso)
VALUES ('$paterno', '$materno', '$nombres', '$correo', '$telefono', '$direccion', '$curso')";

// ejecutar la insercion de datos
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
     if($resultado){
   
   echo "<script>alert('Se agrego nuevo registro');
   window.location='/admin/administrador.html'</script>";
    }else{
        echo  "<script>alert('No se pudo agregar, intenta de nuevo');
window.history.go(-1);</script>";
    }

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

CODIGO CONEXION

```
    <?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "cnu";



$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if (!$conexion) {
    die("Conexión fallo: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conexión exitosa";

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

CODIGO INSERTAR

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

$paterno = $_POST['paterno'];
$materno = $_POST['materno'];
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$curso = $_POST['curso'];

// INSERTAR DATOS A LA BASE 
$insertar = "INSERT INTO registro (paterno, materno, nombres, correo, telefono, direccion, curso)
VALUES ('$paterno', '$materno', '$nombres', '$correo', '$telefono', '$direccion', '$curso')";

// ejecutar la insercion de datos
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
     if($resultado){
   
   echo "<script>alert('Se agrego nuevo registro');
   window.location='/admin/administrador.html'</script>";
    }else{
        echo  "<script>alert('No se pudo agregar, intenta de nuevo');
window.history.go(-1);</script>";
    }

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

[image: ESTRUCTURA BASE DE DATOS]

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ahora si he aqui la solucion:

En tu archivo **conexion.php**, comenta o de preferencia quita las líneas
`mysqli_close($conexion);` esta linea se encarga de cerrar la conexión a la base de datos por eso te marca el error
**Uncaught Error: mysqli object is already closed in...** y cierras la conexión antes de insertar los datos, eso se debe de hacer después de haber insertado.

Y la línea `echo "Conexión exitosa";`, esta línea solo sirve para comprobar que se realizo con éxito la conexión, esta línea solo la necesitas para hacer la validación en desarrollo, en producción esta línea esta de mas
tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "cnu";



$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if (!$conexion) {
    die("Conexión fallo: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que hace falta asignarle la conexion a la variable $conexion

```
$conexion = new mysqli('LOCALHOST', 'USUARIO', 'CONTRASEÑA', 'BASEDATOS');
```

Comment: Este es mi código de conexión , lo he estado cambiando y me sale lo mismo 
  
`<?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$database = "base";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if (!$conexion) {
    die("Conexión fallo: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conexión exitosa";
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>`

Comment: creo que esta linea te esta cerrando la conexion mysqli_close($conexion);, por favor comentala y trata de nuevo

Comment: Me sale lo mismo, dice que la conexion fue exitosa pero sigo teniendo el error en esta linea

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

Comment: creo que esta linea te esta cerrando la conexion mysqli_close($conexion);, por favor comentala y trata de nuevo

Comment: SIGO TENIENDO ERROR 
Conexión exitosa
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli::__construct(): Argument #1 ($hostname) must be of type ?string, mysqli given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\control\registro.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\control\registro.php(18): mysqli->__construct(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO reg...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\control\registro.php on line 18

Comment: podrias publicar el codigo completo, para no estar adivinando (tambien la estructura de la tabla registro)

Comment: Listo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Vamos a intentar una cosa, comenta las lineas `echo "Conexión exitosa";` y `mysqli_close($conexion);` a ver que hace

Comment: @Alx tú también puedes [edit] tu respuesta y crear UNA respuesta con todo lo que debas añadir para ayudarle al OP. Repasa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio bien.